# Will there be a sequel to The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I just saw *The Force Awakens*, and it ended on a cliffhanger (literally, on a cliff).

But seriously will there be another one?

Comment: I'm just curious, is there any particular reason you have to suspect there *won't* be more?

Comment: I think this is a fairly strange question to ask, the answer seems so obvious, it's quite a facile question, and it's not brilliantly worded. (Read: This isn't quite how we like to do things here). But, seriously, I think 8 downvotes on a new user's question is pretty harsh, to be honest. And, I mean, it's not off-topic, it seems like a legitimate question, if not a very inspiring one, and there's nothing here that seems to be hideously against the rules. So, I mean, OP: I hope you won't take that to heart too much and will stick around and just try to improve your posts a little

Comment: @Au101: Hover your mouse over the "downvote" icon, and you'll discover why people are using it.

Answer (score 18):

Yes. Oh god yes. We will drown in oceans of *Star Wars* sequels.

In the short term, Disney has plans to make a complete new trilogy:

- *Episode VIII* is to [be released](https://variety.com/2016/film/news/star-wars-episode-viii-release-date-1201684136/) in December 2017
- *Episode IX* is tentatively to be released [in May 2019](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/star-wars-episode-ix-sets-release-date-997230)

By all accounts, these films will continue the ongoing stories of Rey, Finn, and Kylo Ren.

There are also longer-term plans for a trilogy of *Anthology* films, set in the *Star Wars* universe but not part of the ongoing story of the new trilogy:

- *Rogue One*, released in December 2016, tells the story of the theft of the *Death Star* plans
- The [second](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1585120/the-han-solo-movie-what-we-know-so-far) *Anthology* film is an origin story for Han Solo, currently in pre-production, and is set for a May 2018 release
- The third film has had [few details](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2016/sep/22/star-wars-anthology-movie-2020-disney-confirms-rogue-one) released, but is set for a 2020 release; I've heard rumours that it will center on Boba Fett, but nothing has been confirmed

After this, preliminary talks at Disney could see [a further fifteen years](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/star-wars-bob-iger-reveals-new-han-solo-details-talks-what-happens-episode-ix-988348) worth of *Star Wars*.

If this seems excessive, recall that, at time of writing, *The Force Awakens* is the [highest-grossing domestic film of all time](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/chart/top_lifetime_gross/)<sup>1</sup>, leading *Avatar* by $155 million, and the [third-highest-grossing film worldwide](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/chart/top_lifetime_gross/?area=XWW), trailing *Titanic* by a paltry $120 million and *Avatar* by $720 million.

Unless and until the movies bomb spectacularly<sup>2</sup>, Disney's investors would revolt if they *didn't* keep churning out *Star Wars* movies

---

<sup>1</sup> That's not adjusted for inflation; if you adjust, then *Gone With the Wind* [still wins handily](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/alltime/adjusted.htm), with *The Force Awakens* trailing in 11th place, which is still indescribably impressive

<sup>2</sup> Which seems unlikely, at least in the short-term; *The Phantom Menace* is the 7th highest-domestic-grossing film of all time ($474 million unadjusted), while *Revenge of the Sith* is 25th ($380 million). The lowest of the franchise is actually *Empire Strikes Back*, at 66th ($290 million). Even when they're crap, *Star Wars* makes bank

Comment: Out of curiosity, will the anthology really be "not part of the trilogy continuity"? Or did you mean that they will tell side stories of less important characters?

Comment: @AndresF. What I meant is that they're not part of the story of the new trilogy; I must have been a bit tired when I wrote that before. They're mostly telling backstories; *Rogue One* is about the mission to steal the Death Star plans, I believe, and one of the others is about Han Solo; I'm pretty sure the third is about Boba Fett, but that may have just been a rumour I read somewhere

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes, there will be at least one [sequel trilogy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sequel_trilogy) (episode 7, 8, 9) as well as non-trilogy related films that focus on other events and characters outside the main story (*Rogue One* is currently in production and details events prior to Episode 4):

> The trilogy is comprised of the forthcoming Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens, directed by J.J. Abrams and written by Abrams and Lawrence Kasdan for a release on December 18, 2015; Star Wars: Episode VIII, written and directed by Rian Johnson; and Star Wars: Episode IX, which Johnson is writing a story treatment for.

Answer (score 1):

[The official title for *Star Wars Episode VIII*](https://www.starwars.com/news/the-official-title-for-star-wars-episode-viii-revealed) is *The Last Jedi*:

[image: Title card for The Last Jedi; Black text with red outline reads "Star Wars" with white text reading "The Last Jedi" sandwiched between on a starfield]

Answer (score -1):

According to [this article](https://www.rollingstone.com/movies/movie-news/skywalker-speaks-mark-hamill-on-returning-to-star-wars-46905/3/), yes, and it is already in production:

> in late October, just as the world was starting to wonder about the whereabouts of Luke Skywalker, the guy who plays him was sitting at a table in his tree-lined Malibu yard, wearing Batman-themed Converse sneakers. Hamill was just starting to regrow his Jedi beard for the follow-up, Episode VIII — which would soon need him on set.